# Register link "missing" from home page in home page of unregistered users (Not clear enough)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, homepage, sign-up

When an unregistered user gets to stackoverflow.com he will see:

[image]

As you can see there is no register link.

I think this is confusing since most sites on the Internet <sup>[that sounds horrible](http://hollydoesatx.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cat1.jpg)</sup> offer "register" in there home.

I know this is done like this because of the "particular" login and registering process on StackOverflow, but new users don't know this, so, they might be looking for it.

This is tacitly done in the questions page:

[image]

So I would suggest the same is done for the home page.

Here are some ideas as it how it should look, most are just awful (except the last one) but the point remains, I think the register "concept" should be there somewhere/somehow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And the answer is YES if you were wondering, I'n **that** good at *free hand circling*.

Comment: Should it be Sign Up? (instead of register?)

Comment: @Trufa, sign up and register are synonyms.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: @jjnguy what I ment is which one is used across the site, though they are synonyms if you choose one, you should stick to it, right? :)

Comment: @Trufa, Ah, I see what you mean.  I don't think it matters in this case.  I prefer register though.

Comment: Made sense to me too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a synonym of "log in" -- and there's nowhere enough room for both of these up there.

Comment: I don't particularly agree but I'll admit it isn't necessity. Thanks for the quick response!